# Reducing copy layer size

Tags: docker

Currently I am copying pre-downloaded packages and then installed on the docker image. The **COPY** layer currently has the same size as the directory being copied. Directory is later erased on another layer. Dockerfile looks as follows:

```
COPY python-packages /tmp/python-packages
RUN pip install -f /tmp/python-packages --no-index <pkg-name> \
    && rm -rf /tmp/*
```

Is there a way to copy files without having a layer the same size as the directory being copied? Any way to reduce COPY layer size?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately as of this time you cannot reduce the size or eliminate the layer, `RUN`, `COPY` and `ADD` will create a layer every time.

What you can do is use `pip` to install directly from your version control

e.g. `pip install git+https://git.example.com/MyProject#egg=MyProject`

More info: https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/#vcs-support

This brings the downside that you will have to give access to `pip` if your code is private and will introduce the need for network connectivity on your private network or the internet, depending on where your code is, on docker build time.

You could also use a multi stage build and install the python module with `pip` in another docker image and then just copy the artifacts to the final docker image. I highly **do not recommend** this though unless you have no choice and understand the risks, since you would have to copy all the folders and/or files `pip` touches in the install process and maybe create some others that it expects to be present and also get the permissions right in the final docker image, this will be hard to get right without deep diving in `pip` internals and also hard to maintain in the long run since `pip` might change its files and folders locations and/or structure in the future.

More on multi stage builds: https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/